# Why did "Presets" suddenly appear in my Lightroom's right click -> settings menu?

Tags: lightroom, software

I've been using LR since years. I used to edit many similar photos just by right clicking on the photo, click on settings, and then very near "settings" appeared the submenu "paste from previous".

Yesterday my cat jump onto the keyboard and pressed something. Now on the "settings" menu (after right click), there are listed all the presets. Since I have a lot of presets, the "paste from previous" button went to the top, to give spaces to the presets.

Before yesterday the "paste from settings" was more or less in the area I marked in red.

[image]

For few photos it's not a big deal. But dealing with thousands of photos, the fact that the "paste from previous" went so far in the top, it makes things much slower.

How can I remove the "presets" from the settings menu, as it was until yesterday?

Comment: Assign a shortcut key and be even faster.